# How do you find the cell number of a cell you are running a function in AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently making a function in appscript that can be called from a cell in Spreadsheets. I want to be able to get that cell's number in order to use it, say if the formula is running in cell G3, I want to find that cell and use it in my script.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this once and I seem to recall find that getActiveCell() seems to work.  But I am confident that you will find a condition where it does not work

```
function WHEREAMI(a) {
  let c = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(c);
  return c;
}
```

You don't necessarily need a parameter but if you wish one then adding a cell reference allow you force them to change

Comment: no, it is not necessary. Also this chain `getActiveSheet().getActiveCell()` is reduntant

Answer (score 0):

You can get the A1 notation of the active cell:

```
function getActiveCell() { 
 return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation(); 
}
```

and then call it like that:

[image]